# Insert query takes too long to execute

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables
([SPEEDTEST_D TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtHUk.png) and [LTE_GROUPLIST TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3TBu.png)) where I used left join to insert to my table([LTE_ATHOME_APN_B TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpIX5.png)) but Its taking too long to execute. How do I minimize the time of execution for the insert query?

This is my sql query:

```
INSERT INTO LTE_ATHOME_APN_B (IMSI,Cust_Acc_No,PLAN,PEAK_THROUGHPUT_RECEIVED,
PEAK_THROUGHPUT_SENT,INTERNET_LATENCY,RAN_LATENCY,START_TIME,APN_SERVICE)
SELECT s.IMSI,Cust_Acc_No,PLAN,PEAK_THROUGHPUT_RECEIVED,PEAK_THROUGHPUT_SENT,
INTERNET_LATENCY,RAN_LATENCY,START_TIME,APN_SERVICE
FROM SPEEDTEST_D s
LEFT JOIN LTE_GROUP b ON s.IMSI = b.IMSI
WHERE START_TIME >= '2020-09-01' and APN_SERVICE = 'LTE ATHOME APN'
```

This is the [Explain Select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bzy6Z.png)

Comment: How long time does it take? How many rows are inserted? etc.

Comment: more than hour so i stopped already.700k rows

Comment: Without qualified column names, it is not even clear what the query is doing.